# What is the antonym of "non-stop flight"?

Tags: antonyms

Indirect flight is the antonym of direct flight. However, direct flights and non-stop flights have a  [different](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Non-stop_flight&oldid=1001690677#Compare) meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A direct flight with a layover.

Apparently [flight crew use the term "layover](https://eu.usatoday.com/story/travel/roadwarriorvoices/2015/08/18/the-difference-between-a-stopover-and-layover-and-why-you-should-care/83274870/)" differently from other travellers, and many people (including me 5 minutes ago) would not know the difference between a direct and a non-stop flight, or between a stopover and a layover.

You won't often see this being used, because the main reason to mention that a flight has a layover, is if you will need to change planes, of if you will have a stopover and spend the day in a hotel. If you have a short layover and don't even disembark then it's not very notable.

You could also say "...with a stop at ... to refuel."

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a definitive phrase or word. However, I have seen the following used to convey your meaning: multi-city, multi-hop, and multi-destination.

<s>Of those, I'd say the first is most common, even where the intermediate points aren't actually cities.</s>

Comment: thanks, multi-city often implies a stopover, whereas a non-stop flight could just have a short layover.

Comment: Yep, probably. But I'm pretty sure I've seen it used on various travel booking sites to mean exactly what you are referring to - a flight from A to B with intermediate stops at which at most one may have to change terminal.

Comment: Actually, on second thoughts, you're right. "Multi-city" is more for where there are stopovers. I'm inclined to delete my answer, because it's more wrong than right.

Comment: Thanks, it's ok, you could simply add a notice in the answer.